# How do I slice a NumPy array to get all the values of the same index together?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a NumPy array like this:

```
item = [[0 5] [1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9]]
```

With three sets of the item array, I now have a NumPy array arranged as such:

```
arr = [[[0 5] [1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9]] 
[[0 5] [1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9]]
[[0 5] [1 6] [2 7] [3 8] [4 9]]]
```

0, 1, 2, 3, 4 are values of one variable (a), while 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 are values of another variable (b). I want to arrange an array by index values for both a and b, so all values for index 0 would be in an array for both a and b:

```
a_0 = [0 0 0]
b_0 = [5 5 5]
```

How do I slice this so that I have it like this, where an array exists for each value that occurs at that index:

```
a = [a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4]
b = [b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4]

a = [[0 0 0] [1 1 1] [2 2 2] [3 3 3] [4 4 4]]
b = [[5 5 5] [6 6 6] [7 7 7] [8 8 8] [9 9 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
item = np.array([[0, 5], [1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9]])
arr = np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))
a = arr[:, :, 0].T
b = arr[:, :, 1].T

>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
>>> b
array([[5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```